# The remote server returned an unexpected response: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a client to upload an image to a Java SOAP service using a WCF client. The upload happens as a hex string-encoded byte array.

When uploading an image of 900 KB, I'm getting the error:

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

I tried increasing the maxReceivedMessageSize and other relevant properties in my client's config:

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
   maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>   
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

But this didn't resolve the issue.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image1.Source);
wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 400, 400, 0, 100);
bytearray = ms.ToArray();

string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(bytearray);
```

Here I am returning file to Java Soap Service: See my HEX String and XML Document:

```
StringBuilder stb1 = new StringBuilder();
stb1.Append("<row>");
stb1.Append("<document>");
stb1.Append(hexString).Replace("-", string.Empty);
stb1.Append("</document>");
stb1.Append("</row>");
```

My HexString looks like:

```
FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101006000600000FFDB004300010
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010.........
```

Comment: How large is your request data?

Comment: @TomRedfern I am trying to Add Image of "900 Kb", converting it to "Hex String and triyng to upload it. thanks!! please guide me

Comment: @CodeCaster I haven't added that. I am thinking that is the main issue. i have added web reference, so there is no end point in web.config

Comment: @CodeCaster How to add <service> in web.config?? Thanks

Comment: The server is throwing that exception, so you need to change the server config, not the client config.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, but I do not know how to change it. The web reference I am adding is of "Java Web Service"

Comment: Then you need to contact the author of the service. Nothing you can do here.

Comment: @CodeCaster How do I change "Server Config"?

Comment: @CodeCaster I got it, but from "android" and "ios", they are able to add image using the same service, created in Java

Comment: Please don't randomly air-quote terms, that's not how English works. ["Laser"](http://media.giphy.com/media/qs6ev2pm8g9dS/giphy.gif). Anyway then you need to compare the Android or iOS code to yours. If they can upload a hex string-encoded image of 900 KB, then so should your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster not base64-encoded, but HexString. I have to return image to in HexString form. ok, brother, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Perhaps there's an issue with your code. If you could update your question to include the relevant code where you make a hex string of the file, that'd be nice.

Comment: @CodeCaster see my edited code, I have updated it.thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **Mysterious Microsoft**!!

I removed **name="BasicHttpBinding"** from "**bindings**" element in "**web.config**" and all is well.

my error is solved.

Hohohohoho!!